# Node http res.end

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am currently reading through "Node.js in action" as well as following through a number of online learning resources. One of the first examples in  the book is showing how to pipe a  stream through to a response. Like so:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/png"});
    fs.createReadStream("./image.png").pipe(res);
}).listen(xxxx)
```

My question is how valid is this code? I was under the impression that when ever using the http you should always end with:

```
res.end();
```

Is this not necessary as piping it implies an end? When ever writing a response should I always end it?

Comment: I thought res.end() was only for forcefully stopping responses, like w/ an error code, when there was no data.

Comment: I am unsure, hence the question. A number of places I've seen have said it is important to end a response.

Comment: piping a stream implies it will emit an end event on completion so you dont need an extra res.end()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your readable stream finishes reading (the `image.png` file), by default, it emits and `end()` event, which will call the `end()` event on the writable stream (the `res` stream). You don't need to worry about calling `end()` in this case.

It's worth point out that, in this scenario, your `res` will no longer be writable after the `end()` event is called. So, if you want to keep it writable, just pass the `end: false` option to `pipe()`, like:

```
fs.createReadStream("./image.png").pipe(res, { end: false });
```

, and then call the `end()` event sometime in the future.

Answer (score 0):

end() is not necessary for streams.  There is a great set of tutorials [here](https://github.com/rvagg/learnyounode).  One of the exercises (#11 http file server with streams) is to create a static file server.  here is what the code looks like:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http'),
    port = parseInt( process.argv[2] ),
    file = process.argv[3],
    opts = { encoding:'utf8' },
    server;

server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log( 'request url: ', req.url );

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type':'text/plain' });
    var stream = fs.createReadStream( file );
    stream.pipe( res );

    stream.on('end', function() {
        console.log('stream ended...');
    });
});


server.listen( port, function() {
    console.log('server listening on port: ', port );
});
```

Lots of other good tutorials and examples as well.  Hope this helps.